# How to remove highlights tags before in Azure Cognitive Search documents before searching

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Azure Search by default highlights search results with `<em>` tag. I've met with situation where user uploads document with that tag inside:

```
<em>Today</em> topic will be...
```

When i would search for "topic" i would get:

```
<em>Today</em> <em>topic</em> will be...
```

And i wouldn't be able to distinguish the right highlight.

I know that i can modify highlight_pre_tag and highlight_post_tag so i would avoid this in this particular situation. But is there other way to encode this tags before appyling highlighs?

EDIT:
By encoding i mean getting something like this:

```
&lt;em&gt;Today&lt;/em&gt; <em>topic</em> will be...;
```

So I can send it to frontend and then display `&lt;em&gt;` from "Today" as `<em>` and use `<em>` in "topic" to highlight it to yellow.

Comment: `But is there other way to encode this tags before appyling highlighs?` - Can you describe what you mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Search doesn't provide any built-in mechanism to modify the "raw" content of a document if you are using the Index API directly, however, if you are using one of our built-in indexers, you can look into using the [field mapper functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings#field-mapping-functions) (such as the UrlEncode function) or create your own [custom skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-web-api) (if you want to only apply very specific rules) to transform the documents in transit from your data source to the search index.

Alternatively, we've seen customers use custom highlight pre and post tags that are easily recognizable (and unlikely to be mistaken for original content) and then using a simple search and replace function in their client application to transform those back into the desired tag.

For example, using

> pre-tag : "!HIGHLIGHT_START!" and post-tag :"!HIGHLIGHT_END!"

and then using

> String.Replace("!HIGHLIGHT_START!", "<em>")

before displaying the results in their application. That way, any client-side logic that requires finding the actual highlights can use the custom tags, while still showing the desired tag in the UX.